# How to enable Cloud Firestore Native Mode using API / command line?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing a script for setting up a Google Cloud project and I'd like to use Firestore. A new project, however, is by default in [Datastore mode](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore).

Switching to Firestore can easily be done using the web interface in the cloud console but I'd like to automate it. Is there any API or command line tool (gcloud? firebase?) for enabling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of today (30 Apr 2019), there is no API or command line to set the mode for Cloud Firestore.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately still acurate. Command line / API support is still pretty bad in january 2020.

Comment: Actually, you can use the command line with gcloud alpha datastore/firestore databases create (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/datastore/databases, https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases)

Comment: I stand corrected Jim, I did not check the alpha commands. So it appears more support is slowly coming. Hopefully the APIs can also be used for Terraform soon.

Comment: Despite the alpha command group's description of `manage Creation of Cloud Firestore in Native mode Database`, the only command in the group is **create** with `Create a Google Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode database`. The output of the command is `Success! Confirmed selection of a Google Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode`. So there really is no way to create/switch it to *Native* without the Web UI Console.

Answer (score 2):

Things seem to have changed by now (03 Jan 2022). I managed to set up a new Firestore with gcloud using the following commands.
Native mode is chosen by default:

`gcloud app create --region=us-central`
`gcloud firestore databases create --region=us-central`

also see the documentation for
[app create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/create) and [firestore database create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/create).