# Programmatically adding Firestore to a new Firebase project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-sdk

I am currently attempting to automate a lot of the processes involved in creating a new Firebase project. The end goal is being able to run a script and having a fully configured Firebase and GCloud-project with everything deployed and ready for production.

I've managed to create a script, which creates a new Firebase and Google Cloud project, downloads a service-key, sets the default region for the project, enables the APIs I want and deploys a set of cloud functions. This was all done using a combination of the GCloud/Firebase CLI and various GCloud APIs.

It seems like Cloud Storage was automatically enabled for the project when I set the default Cloud Platform region.

Unfortunately, I am currently blocked by having no way to actually add Firestore to the newly created Firebase-project without manually entering the Firebase Console and clicking 'Create database'.

When I attempt to deploy my security rules to Firestore, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error: 400, Project '<Project-name>' is not a Cloud Firestore enabled project.
```

When I try to interact with firebase via the admin SDK, I get the following error:

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Cloud Datastore projects
```

I've tried adding Firestore via the CLI by running the following CLI-command:

```
gcloud services enable firestore.googleapis.com
```

The above command does make Firestore appear in the list of enabled services on both Google Cloud Platform Console and via the Google Cloud CLI, but it doesn't actually fix the errors I get when trying to interact with Firestore.

Does anyone know of a way to enable Firestore for Firebase using either the Firebase/GCloud CLI or an API? It might only require 2 clicks on the console, but it interrupts the entire automated process I'm building towards.

EDIT: Several months after asking this question, Google added an alpha version of an [API](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/databases/create) that will add Firestore to an existing Firebase project.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55923900/4457030

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for pointing me towards that answer. It is regrettable that such a seemingly simple feature isn't available.