# Firebase using gapi client sets defaultLocation:finalize to Datastore mode instead of Native mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-js-client

Using `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` I am trying to add firebase including Firestore to a GCP project programmatically instead of using the console. When I issue the below command this creates a Datastore instead of a Firebase Native Mode for Firestore.

```
gapi.client.firebase.projects.defaultLocation.finalize({parent: 'projects/bcc-test-26', locationId: 'us-central'})
```

These are the discovery Docs that I am using

```
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
    discoveryDocs: [
      'https://firebase.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1',
      'https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1',
      'https://firebase.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1',
      'https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta1',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/compute/v1/rest',
      'https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'
    ]
```

Also here is the log if helpful

```
5:56 PM
Completed: google.firebase.service.v1beta1.FirebaseProjectService.FinalizeDefaultLocation
Alex Patterson has executed google.firebase.service.v1beta1.FirebaseProjectService.FinalizeDefaultLocation on bcc-test-26
5:56 PM
storage.setIamPermissions
firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com has executed storage.setIamPermissions on bcc-test-26.appspot.com
5:56 PM
Completed: Create App Engine application
firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com created bcc-test-26
5:56 PM
Create bucket
firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com created bcc-test-26.appspot.com
5:56 PM
Create bucket
firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com created staging.bcc-test-26.appspot.com
5:56 PM
Create App Engine application
firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com created bcc-test-26
5:56 PM
google.firebase.service.v1beta1.FirebaseProjectService.FinalizeDefaultLocation
Alex Patterson has executed google.firebase.service.v1beta1.FirebaseProjectService.FinalizeDefaultLocation on bcc-test-26
```

---

I think that I "may" have found a duplicate question, that actually explains what happened. It appears that as of May 8th 2020 you cannot create a Native Firestore via REST API.

[How to enable Cloud Firestore Native Mode using API / command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885918/how-to-enable-cloud-firestore-native-mode-using-api-command-line)

It seems that the feature is in alpha in gcloud CLI, so maybe soon?

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/datastore/databases

Comment: Are you creating a new project at the same time? When you create a new Firestore database, you must select a database mode. You cannot use both Native mode and Datastore mode in the same project.

Comment: Hey John, I first create a GCP project, then add Firebase, then finalize. Of course waiting for the operation to complete between each step.

```
gapi.client.cloudresourcemanager.projects.create({name: project.projectName,projectId: project.projectId});
gapi.client.firebase.projects.addFirebase({project: `projects/${projectId}`})
gapi.client.firebase.projects.defaultLocation.finalize({parent: 'projects/bcc-test-26', locationId: 'us-central'})
```

Comment: You may consult https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact